# The question about paying credit on Design automation

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am using Forge design automation function in the project.
I checked the cost at https://forge.autodesk.com/pricing.
It is said that 6 credits are consumed per hour.

I tested credit consumption per execution once in my project.
Two credits were consumed for one run.
In my project, the work lasts about 30 seconds, but I don't know why 2 credits are paid.

Please tell me how to calculate credit consumption.

Answer (score 0):

The tooltip on the pricing page says:

> Every second of processing Work Items (*including file transfer time between systems*) submitted through the Design Automation API is included in the number of processing hours.

Since you haven't provided any details it's hard to say, but please note that downloading of input files and uploading of output files is also included in the processing time.

What kind of task did you try and run in the Design Automation service? Was it perhaps inputting or outputting some large design file?

Comment: When I tested, I conducted the test with a simple file consisting of four walls.  Design Automation was used to adjust the length of the wall.

Comment: Could you share the logfile that's generated by the Design Automation work item?